# Even though my code is correct, I encounter an error

Tags: c++

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Employee.h"

using namespace std;
 
  
int main(){
 
    Employee Crexy;
    Crexy.age=18;
    Crexy.name="Crexy";
    Crexy.department="Computer Engineering";
    Crexy.ID=8;
    Crexy.salary=10000;
    Crexy.ShowInfos();


    return 0;
}
```

Employee.cpp

```
#include "Employee.h"
#include <iostream>
void Employee::ShowInfos() {
    cout << Employee::name  << endl;  
    cout << Employee::age  << endl;  
    cout << Employee::department  << endl;  
    cout << Employee::ID  << endl;  
    cout << Employee::salary  << endl;  

}
```

Employee.h

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED
#define EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Employee{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    string department;
    int ID;
    int salary;

    void ShowInfos();
};



#endif // EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED
```

Error :  undefined reference to `Employee::ShowInfos()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I thought everything is OK but i got an error. What's the reason of error, can someone help me? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: How are you compiling this code? You are missing `#include <string>` in your header file, and `using namespace std;` in a header is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm just learning programming so I don't know how i can answer this question, with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio Code, chances are you're using the default code-runner plugin, which builds only the active file. Please read [the Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs), especially the parts for the Microsoft C++ plugin (for your compiler and OS combination) for how to build projects using multiple files.

Comment: If you're already using the Microsoft C++ plugin, you need to update your `tasks.json` file to list all the source (but not header) files to be built.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you're right. Thanks guys for your helping.